# Google Api get token request returns invalid_request

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I'm trying to get Google APi's access_token using c# and always getting error message invalid_request. There is my code:

```
var Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Params["client_id"] = GoogleApplicationAPI.CLIENT_ID;
Params["client_secret"] = GoogleApplicationAPI.CLIENT_SECRET;
Params["code"] = "4/08Z_Us0a_blkMlXihlixR1579TYu.smV5ucbI8U4VOl05ti8ZT3ZD4CgMcgI";
Params["redirect_uri"] = GoogleApplicationAPI.RETURN_URL;
Params["grant_type"] = "authorization_code";

var RequestData = "";
foreach (var Item in Params)
{
    RequestData += Item.Key + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Item.Value) + "&";
}

string Url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post.ToString();
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

var SendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestData);
try
{
    request.ContentLength = SendData.Length;
    Stream OutputStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    OutputStream.Write(SendData, 0, SendData.Length);
} catch {}

try
{
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
    {
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        string JSON = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
} catch {}
```

I use https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the call to `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` on each item in the request data. You shouldn't need to do this as the data is not going into the url it's being POSTed. This is no doubt diluting the information being sent which is resulting in your `Invalid Request` response.

Comment: You seem to be hard-coding the `code` parameter, wouldn't this be expired after a certain length of time?

Comment: In fact, I get the code so `var Code = Request.Params["code"];`.

Comment: @AlexeyLisikhin that's not what your example shows, is there any other information returned with the error? Usually the response has some information telling you *why* you got the invalid response.

Comment: @AlexeyLisikhin hmm the only thing I can think of is the encoding of the data is wrong. However, you said removing `UrlEncode` didn't change anything. You might be best checking the request being sent using something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to make sure it looks ok.

Comment: @MartinBories yes, I solve this. Just don't use UrlEncode and be sure, what you response right parameters.

Comment: On the API playground - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ - We clearly see that the redirect URI in the post body is URL encoded:

code=4%2F-C-yAfVE5qMMVgR3iOPL8AONp20P.8k8bYvTxsoQemmS0T3UFEsOcfQmDfwI&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=&client_secret=************&grant_type=authorization_code